# What is the default strategy of nth_element on Eigen library members?

Tags: c++, sorting, std, eigen, stdvector

I have seen a piece of code:

```
template<class T>
T getMedian(vector<T>& data_vec)
{
    assert(!data_vec.empty());
    typename vector<T>::iterator it = data_vec.begin()+floor(data_vec.size()/2);
    nth_element(data_vec.begin(), it, data_vec.end());
    return *it;
}
```

Lets say for example, `T` is `vector2D``  in eigen library. What is the sort rule by default? (comparing the vector norm or something else?)

I have had a search through internet but failed to get any clue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't compile because there is no `operator<` defined for `Eigen::Matrix`. So you need to provide your own comparison functor to `nth_element` implementing the strategy of your choice.